# Automatic update Master Zone nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have created a nameserver on a VPS. I have created a master zone on the nameserver, and this works fine.

I have also created a slave zone for the master. I see that when I update the master zone, then the slave is automatic updated.

Now the VPS I have created is only a nameserver. Now I have a lot of websites on different hosting companies, mostly in directadmin. I want to do the DNS in directadmin on the hosting machines.

Now I want to know if it is possible that when I change the DNS on the hosting machine, that the master zone automatically updates the fields.

It is not possible for me to create a nameserver at the hosting company, because they do not have any unique ip adresses.

This is the reason that I have my nameserver at a different VPS, and just point to my webhosting.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways I know of a DNS architecture:

- The other hosting machines are setup to send their DNS changes to the master and the master remains as the master. This is usually a control panel setup. I don't know about DirectAdmin.
- The other hosting machines are setup to each be a "hidden master" and the real master instead slaves the hosting machines. The internet only knows about the slave DNS server.

This latter only works so far because new domains have to be manually set up to slave the zone unless, like the former, the control panel or some other system is setup to do so automatically.

Comment: Thank you the first option looks like a good deal. I have to figure out if my hosting provider supports this option.